# ReferenceError: Media is not defined in Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

I am creating an app in Ionic which plays audio in the app. I am using `cordova-plugin-media` for playing audio. In android the music is not playing and in browser it throws an `ReferenceError` :

```
ReferenceError: Media is not defined
at ChildScope.$scope.playAudio (observationCtrl.js:4)
at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:26325), <anonymous>:4:218)
at ionic.bundle.js:62239
at ChildScope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29026)
at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29125)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:62238)
at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16451)
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2906)
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2895)
at HTMLDocument.tapTouchEnd (ionic.bundle.js:3022)
```

Is there is any problem in my code or ionic1 does not support this plugin.
 my code for playing the audio :

```
$scope.playAudio = function(src) {
    var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
    media.play();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `Media` constructor could not be referenced. Did you install the plugin? This plugin defines a global Media Constructor.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
```

Then [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/#mediaplay) example for playing Audio should work -

```
function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,

    // success callback
    function () {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },

    // error callback
    function (err) {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
    }
    );

    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```